# Re-writing without using symmetry tactic

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

This is the coq version I'm using:

```
sibi { ~ }-> coqc --version
The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.4pl4 (November 2015)
compiled on Nov 04 2015 12:56:53 with OCaml 4.02.3
```

This is the theorem I'm trying to prove:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Theorem rev_app_distr: forall l1 l2 : list nat,
  rev (l1 ++ l2) = rev l2 ++ rev l1.
Proof.
```

Note that I will use this theorem in the proof (which has already been proved by me):

```
Theorem app_nil_r : forall l : list nat,
  l ++ [] = l.
```

Ok, now this is my attempt to prove the theorem via the usual induction way:

```
Theorem rev_app_distr: forall l1 l2 : list nat,
  rev (l1 ++ l2) = rev l2 ++ rev l1.
Proof.
  intros l1 l2.
  induction l1 as [| n l1'].
  - simpl.
    rewrite -> app_nil_r with (l := rev l2) at 2.
```

But on executing the `rewrite` tactic, it gives me the following error:

```
Error: Tactic failure:Nothing to rewrite.
```

But If I use `symmetry` tactic, I can actually prove it via the same code:

```
Theorem rev_app_distr: forall l1 l2 : list nat,
  rev (l1 ++ l2) = rev l2 ++ rev l1.
Proof.
  intros l1 l2.
  induction l1 as [| n l1'].
  - simpl.
    symmetry.
    rewrite -> app_nil_r with (l := rev l2) at 1.
```

So, why does rewriting it without symmetry doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that you were missing the `symmetry` call, but that you added the `at 2` modifier when invoking the tactic.  Since the goal at that point has only one occurrence of the left-hand side of `app_nil_r` (that is, `rev l2 ++ []`), the `rewrite` tactic gets confused and does not do anything.  If you replace `at 2` by `at 1`, or simply delete it, the problem goes away.  You can learn more about the `at` modifier in the [Coq manual](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic121).

Comment: Thanks, that solves it. Where can I learn more about `at` ? Is there a reference doc for it. Googling didn't yield any valid results. I actually learned about `at` by looking at other people's code.

Comment: I just added a reference to the Coq documentation.